# scanf from child scans whatever parent had already scanned

Tags: c, process, fork, scanf

My program, along with its two child processes all read input from stdin in an orderly fashion.
The problem I found was that this:

Given this input:

```
32
51453a
140
```

Parent process reads 32, that means the 1st child process needs to read 2 more numbers. The parent process then sends 1 byte through pipe to signal the 1st process it needs to read two numbers. When the child process picks up the signal and starts reading those numbers, instead of 51453a and 140 the child reads 32 51453a.

I've been struggling with understanding why this happens, how I can fix it or better yet, how I can avoid it.

I'm running on Mac OSX

Edit: this issue only occurs when the input is being redirected from a file (running ./polygon < in.txt). When running from console directly it does not happen. 
Also added more code to provide a better picture.

```
void runWriterProcess(char *outFile, int writerFd[2]) {
    close(writerFd[1]);
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    dup(writerFd[0]);
    close(writerFd[0]);
    char *const params[] = {"./writer", outFile, NULL};
    execv("./writer", params);
}
void reader32(int INSIG, int OUTPUT) {
    long unsigned polygonParts[2];
    char runSignal[2], polygonBuffer[17];
    int64 nextPolygon;
    while(read(INSIG, runSignal, 1) > 0) {
        scanf("%lx", &polygonParts[0]);
        scanf("%lx", &polygonParts[1]);
        nextPolygon = polygonParts[1];
        nextPolygon = nextPolygon << 32;
        nextPolygon += polygonParts[0];
        sprintf(polygonBuffer, "%16llx", nextPolygon);
        write(OUTPUT, polygonBuffer, (int)strlen(polygonBuffer));
    }
    finishError("reader32\0");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void reader64(int INSIG, int OUTPUT) {
    char runSignal[2], polygonBuffer[17];
    int64 nextPolygon;
    while(read(INSIG, runSignal, 1) > 0) {
        scanf("%16llx", &nextPolygon);
        sprintf(polygonBuffer, "%16llx", nextPolygon);
        write(OUTPUT, polygonBuffer, 16);
    }
    finishError("reader64\0");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void runMainLoop(int reader32, int reader64, int readPipe) {
    long unsigned dummy[2];
    int64 bigDummy, nextPolygon;
    char polygonBuffer[17];
    int readerToRun;
    for(;;) {
        scanf("%d", &readerToRun);
        if (readerToRun == 32) {
            write(reader32, "1", 1);
        } else {
            write(reader64, "1", 1);
        }
        read(readPipe, polygonBuffer, 16);
        sscanf(polygonBuffer, "%16llx", &nextPolygon);
        if(runOnPolygon(nextPolygon)) break;
    }
    write(reader64, "0\n", 2);
}

void createReaders(pid_t *reader32pid, pid_t *reader64pid) {
    int fd32[2], fd64[2], fdBoth[2], readerToRun;
    long unsigned polygonParts[2];
    int64 nextPolygon, dummy;
    char runSignal[2], polygonBuffer[17];
    polygonBuffer[16] = '\0';
    pipe(fd32);
    pipe(fd64);
    pipe(fdBoth);
    if ((*reader32pid = fork()) == 0) {
        close(fd32[1]);
        close(fd64[0]);
        close(fd64[1]);
        close(fdBoth[0]);
        reader32(fd32[0], fdBoth[1]);
    }
    if ((*reader64pid = fork()) == 0) {
        close(fd32[0]);
        close(fd32[1]);
        close(fd64[1]);
        close(fdBoth[0]);
        reader64(fd64[0], fdBoth[1]);
    }
    close(fd32[0]);
    close(fd64[0]);
    close(fdBoth[1]);
    runMainLoop(fd32[1], fd64[1], fdBoth[0]);
    close(fd32[1]);
    close(fd64[1]);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    finishError("main_process\0");
}

void finishError(char processName[13]) {
    char output[50];
    sprintf(output, "%s pid=%d is going to exit\n", processName, getpid());
    write(STDERR_FILENO, output, strlen(output) + 1);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{   
    polygonList.head = NULL;
    polygonList.tail = NULL;
    pid_t writerPid, reader32pid, reader64pid;
    int writerFd[2];
    char outFile[11];
    scanf("%s", outFile);
    pipe(writerFd);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        runWriterProcess(outFile, writerFd);
    } else {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup(writerFd[1]);
        close(writerFd[0]);
        close(writerFd[1]);
        createReaders(&reader32pid, &reader64pid);
    }
    freeList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the input coming from a file or from the terminal — that is, are you typing those 3 lines to the program, or is that information coming from a file? I'm not sure what your code is up to because it isn't an MCVE ([MCVE]); there isn't a `main()` there. I'm not clear if it is as simple as: `int main(void) { pid_t p32; pid_t p64; return createReaders(&p32, &p64); }` or whether there's a lot of other important work going on (such as reading some information from standard input). Buffering is probably (almost certainly) part of the story, but there are some intricacies that are not yet explained.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and editing. I've added more information as suggested.

Comment: The extra information about 'only when reading from file' means that the symptoms make sense, and the fact that you read the output file name from standard input before getting the data that you ask about was what I expected to make sense of what you were seeing, but it wasn't clear that is what you were doing.  The read of the file name pulls the first buffer full of the file into the standard input buffer when you're reading from a file (or the whole file if the file is smaller than the buffer size — and that's the internal standard i/O buffer I'm referring to).  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ After that read, you fork, and the parent and children all have the same data pending in their individual file streams.  You'd get some more interesting effects if the processes needed to read more buffers full from the file; they still share an open file description (distinct from an open file descriptor!) so the first process to read a buffer full would move the read pointer of the other two processes, and the other two processes would not automatically see the data read by the first process.  Beware!

Comment: That helped me understand everything even better. Thanks a lot Jonathan! And sorry for not providing enough explanation to begin with, I'll make sure not to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Someprogrammerdude already explained why this happens.  If indeed you cannot avoid parent and child (or multiple children) reading from the standard input, then you have the alternative of setting it to unbuffered via the `setvbuf()` function.  If you do this, you should do it first thing, before anything at all is read from `stdin`:

```
int result = setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
if (result != 0) {
    // handle error
}
```

Do note that this has performance implications.

Comment: That did the trick! I also noticed that it only happens when my input is getting redirected from a file on opposed to getting written in the console. Any idea why this is affecting the buffer?

Comment: @user4370437, When the input is redirected from a file, it will by default by fully buffered.  When it is from a terminal, it will by default be line-buffered.  If line-buffering is sufficient for the case of redirection from a file then you could use the same function to force line-buffering instead of turning off buffering altogether.  Read its docs for details.

Answer (score 3):

It's called *buffering*. When you `fork` the child is an almost complete copy of the parent process, including things like input buffers.

The best solution (IMO) is to *not* read from standard input in the child. Instead have the parent process do all input, and then send it all over the pipe to the child.

Comment: In this case, I have to read from the stdin since that's one of the assignment rules. Any ideas on how to fix it without changing this logic?